# Scala - Declaring val fields and initializing them inside methods

Tags: scala

I want to declare few val fields and initialize them inside an init method so that I can use these fields throughout the scope of the class of which they are part of.

Ex.

```
Class A {

  val field1 
  val field2

  def init():Unit{
  ----
  ----
  field1 = ----
  ----
  ----
  field2 = ----
  }
}
```

I know this may not be a best practice to do in functional oriented Scala because init() method in above case has side effects.

How should we handle the above requirement in Scala for field declaration and assignment where we do not know the value of the field upfront but need to execute some logic to derive the value of that field?

Sorry, this might be too basic question to ask but I am new to Scala coming from Java background so my mind thinks like we do in Java world.

Comment: If you want to initialize then modify, you cannot do it with val, you need var.

I think you want to use an object and directly initialize the vals

Comment: You might want to declare the fields as `lazy val`. When you do that, they won't be initialized until you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the answer with thanks to @Tim's input:

In the below example I calculate the `public` members `field1, field2, field3` via the `init` method that gets some constructor args and returns a tuple

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean, d: List[Double]) {
  lazy val (field1, field2, field3): (String, Double, Boolean) = init(a, b, c, d) // lazy is optional (see comment below)

  private def init(w: Int, x: String, y: Boolean, z: List[Double]): (String, Double, Boolean) = {
    (
      x + w,
      z.sum,
      y & w %2 == 0
    )
  }
}

val a = new A(1, "sss", true, List(1d, 2.1, 3.14))

println(a.field1)
println(a.field2)
println(a.field3)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

sss1
6.24
false
defined class A
a: A = A@52a7928a
```

This is not the best form of functional programming, I suppose. But, there are no mutations such as you would have with a `var`. If your `init` method is like mine that only evaluates some external params and calculates a fixed value for a `val` members of the class, that would be alright.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-examples-constructors-case-classes-parameters

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html

Comment: Hi Yaneeve, thanks for responding. My init calculates several fixed values (not just one) to be assigned to several class fields, so I can not use its return value for the assignment to any particular field.

Comment: @Ankur You can assign multiple variables in one expression: `val (field1, field2, field3) = init()`. The `init` function will return a tuple of values. If you use `lazy val` then `init` will be called when the first one of the tuples is used.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for replying in my absence :). Ankur that would have been my recommendation as well

Comment: My pleasure! Perhaps you could update your answer with this so that it is there for other people with the same question.

Comment: @Tim and Yaneeve- Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

As suggested by **marstran** you can use lazy val for that purpose like this:

```
lazy val field1:T

def initilizeField1(value:T): T ={
field1:T = value
}
```

Where T is the generic type of your val field1.

```
class A {
    lazy val field1: Int = initilizeField1(5)

    def initilizeField1[T](value:T): T ={
      value
    }
  }
```

Comment: This does not compile: you need to provide more code to explain your solution.

Comment: @Tim i explaind the idea not the code and i think author will understand the idea it's not for you actually. If he will as for the explanation i will give him.

Comment: I don't understand the idea, so could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Tim i think now you can understand how to use both of the fields i have written before it was just the metter of use and i thought that it's not that tough to use if you know the idea.

Comment: @Raman - Thanks but I actually got confused by first set of code given by you as it gave compile error and that code gave an impression that lazy can be used to declare a field and "leave it uninitialized at declaration and initialize it later".